# What OST is played in episode 2 when Shinichi catches three rocks?

Tags: music, parasyte

I have tried downloading all OSTs of Parasyte -the maxim- but couldn't find it. Although I didn't listen to every song really carefully and just quickly "walked" through them, but still I couldn't find it. To be precise, I am asking about what OST is played in [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA_6M5Yjn4Q).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The song is called ["Kill the Puppets"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ-jtpej6eg) and the excerpt from your youtube link probably starts about a minute and 10 seconds into the song.